# List of overlapping WMS layers

Tags: leaflet, wms, overlapping-features, getfeatureinfo

How do I get a list of layers by clicking on overlapping WMS layers in the Leaflet map?  The best solution is to have the list in a single popup on the map.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>WMS Leaflet</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <style> 

     body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        html, body, #map {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

    .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper {
    width: 420px;
    height: 400px;
    }

    iframe {
    width: 400px;
    height: 350px;
    }
    </style> 
</head>  
    <body>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet.wms@0.2.0/dist/leaflet.wms.min.js"></script> 

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.5.0/proj4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4leaflet/1.0.2/proj4leaflet.js"></script>

    <div id ="map"> </div> 
    <script>

        var map =
  L.map('map', {
    center: [43.731739, 10.401401],
    zoom: 2,
    // minZoom:12,
  });   


var options = {'transparent': true};
var source = L.WMS.source("http://geoportale.regione.lazio.it/geoserver_nsit/ptpr/wms", options);
var layer1 = source.getLayer('zone_umide');
var layer2 = source.getLayer('aree_protette');
var control = L.control.layers({}, {
    'Layer 1': layer1,
    'Layer 2': layer2
})
control.addTo(map);

    </script>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand the problem, You can't use a GetFeatureInfo to discover a list of layers (as per tag), because you need to specify the layers you want to query in the request... in other words you must know the list of layers before doing the query.

Comment: Are you asking about features already displayed on the map or the ones on server that could be displayed?

Comment: I'm asking about features already displayed on the map

Comment: using getfeatureinfo I have difficulty append the results in a single popup

Comment: What are those difficulties? Edit your question and add your code of what you have tried so far and doesn't work.

Comment: Are all the layers from the same service

Comment: yes but I would also like to add other wms of other services

Comment: For multiple layers in the same WMS, use a WMS 1.3.0 request and LAYERS and QUERY_LAYERS parameters should have all layers in the service.  If the service conforms to the WMS standard you should get one feature per layer (assuming each  layer is marked as queryable). If there are no features at the point location, you should still get a null response.

Answer (score 1):

Initially it was not mentioned in the question that `leaflet.wms.js` plugin is used to retrieve WMS layers. This plugin has built-in functionality to display WMS layers info in popup upon click on the map, retrieved from server with `GetFeatureInfo` request .

Unluckily there are several problems with implementation of this popup and also the fact that there might be CORS violation problems when retrieving feature info from server.

First problem is how info in the deafult popup looks like. It's simply all the text, retrived from server, for example:

[image]

This looks pretty useless, but text itsel has some structure that could be parsed and retrieve only relevant data:

```
Results for FeatureType 'https://geoportale.regione.lazio.it/geoserver_nsit/ptpr:aree_protette':
--------------------------------------------
geom = [GEOMETRY (Polygon) with 39 points]
nome = Monte Rufeno
vincolo = Riserva Naturale Regionale
comuni = Acquapendente
ente_gest = Comune di Acquapendente
provincia = Viterbo
anno_istit = 1983.0
istitucion = L.R. 19 settembre 1983, n. 66 (B.U.R. 10 ottobre 1983, n. 28)
nota = Il perimetro comprende i terreni del demanio regionale proveniente dai beni dell'azienda di Stato per le foreste demanial . Non ha valenza giuridica e/o probatoria. Sup. (Ha) A¨ desunta dalla presente perimetrazione
rif_cartog = IGM Serie 25/V
categoria = Riserva naturale
cod_euap = EUAP0273
admapkey = 17
pianificaz = 
data = Riferimento dati: settembre 2014
id_rl = f008
allegati = PTPR_art_37
gu_bu_data = B.U. n. 28 del 10.10.1983
objectid = 0
zona = 
id_ma = 
operatore = 
shape_area = 2968.95409049759
shape_len = 63966.45559087736
--------------------------------------------
```

The second problem with this partucular WMS server is that when `GetFeatureInfo` request is sent for more than one layer at once, it returns info only for the first layer.

But luckily this popup functionality has various hooks than can be used to manipulate what requsts are sen to WMS server and what will be displayed in popup. To not complicate to much, the simplest way to get desired info in desired form in popup is first to  modify `getFeatureInfo` hook to send `GetFeatureInfo` request separately for each layer, and second, to modify `showFeatureInfo` hook, which gets as parameters text formated info from WMS request and lat,lng coordinates.

Since text retreived form server has some simple structure, it can be parsed to get desired info into popup.

In the code below `GetFeatureInfo` method of `L.WMS.Source` object is modified with `include` method to retrieve information for each layer separately. `showFeatureInfo` method is modified to extract only desired info from WMS feature info and then display it in popup. Simple `getInfo` parser is used for parsing. Code has to be inserted before WMS source creation.

```
function getInfo(info, start, end) {
  var i, j, retVal;

  i = info.indexOf(start);
  if (i > 0) {
    j = info.indexOf(end, i)
    retVal = info.slice((i + start.length), j);
    }
  else {
    retVal = '';
  }
  return retVal;
}

L.WMS.Source = L.WMS.Source.include({
  'showFeatureInfo': function(latlng, info) {
    console.log(info);
    var popupContent = '';
    info.forEach(function(info) {
      var layerId = getInfo(info, '/ptpr:', "'");
      if (layerId == 'aree_protette') {
        popupContent += '<p><u>Aree protete</u><br>' +
                       getInfo(info, 'nome = ', '\n') + '<br>' +
                       getInfo(info, 'vincolo = ', '\n');
        }
      else if (layerId == 'zone_umide') {
        popupContent += '<p><u>Zone umide</u><br>' +
                       getInfo(info, 'Denominazione = ', '\n') + '<br>';
      }
    });
    if (popupContent.length > 0) {
      L.popup({className: 'popup'})
        .setLatLng(latlng)
        .setContent(popupContent)
        .openOn(map);
    }
  },

  'getFeatureInfo': function(point, latlng, layers, callback) {
    var i;
    var j = 0;
    var allText = [];
    for (i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
      var tmpLayer = [0];
      tmpLayer[0] = layers[i];
      var params = this.getFeatureInfoParams(point, tmpLayer);
      var url = this._url + L.Util.getParamString(params, this._url);

      this.showWaiting();
      this.ajax(url, done);

      function done(result) {
        this.hideWaiting();
        var text = this.parseFeatureInfo(result, url);
        allText[j++] = text;
        if (j == layers.length) {
          callback.call(this, latlng, allText);
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Now upon click on point in the map with two overlapping layers, the following popup appears:

[image]

With this particaular WMS server there still remains CORS violation problem. Plugin tries to deal with it by retrieving `GetFeatureInfo` info through `<iframe>` and in this case we have even less control over it. If we are running our page on our own server, simple solution is to write simple 'proxy' page that retrieves infor for us from the server.

In my case server is an old MS IIS with ASP, on which such 'proxy' page can look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>  
<body>
<%
  Dim result, site, xmlhttp

  site = URLDecode(request.querystring("site"))

  Response.expires = -1

  Set xmlhttp = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

  Call xmlhttp.Open("GET", site, False)
  Call xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=UTF-8")
  Call xmlhttp.send()

  If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
    Response.write(Err.Number & " Source: " & Err.Source & " Desc: " &  Err.Description)
    Err.Clear
  Else
    result = xmlhttp.ResponseText
    Response.Write(result)
  End If

  Function URLDecode(StringToDecode)  
    Dim TempAns
    Dim CurChr

    CurChr = 1    
    Do Until CurChr - 1 = Len(StringToDecode)
      Select Case Mid(StringToDecode, CurChr, 1)
        Case "+"
          TempAns = TempAns & " "
        Case "%"
          TempAns = TempAns & Chr(CLng("&h" & Mid(StringToDecode, CurChr + 1, 2)))
           CurChr = CurChr + 2
        Case Else
          TempAns = TempAns & Mid(StringToDecode, CurChr, 1)
      End Select
      CurChr = CurChr + 1
    Loop

    URLDecode = TempAns
  End Function
%>
</body> 
</html>
```

In case of PHP, such 'proxy' page is extremely simple:

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents($_GET["site"]);
echo $content;
?>
```

In the case of using such proxy, `getFeatureInfo` hook has to be modified to route request through proxy, which in my case is `lib/asp/proxy.asp?site=`:

```
'getFeatureInfo': function(point, latlng, layers, callback) {
  var i;
  var j = 0;
  var allText = [];
  for (i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
    var tmpLayer = [0];
    tmpLayer[0] = layers[i];
    var params = this.getFeatureInfoParams(point, tmpLayer);
    var url = this._url + L.Util.getParamString(params, this._url);
    var proxyUrl = 'lib/asp/proxy.asp?site=' + encodeURIComponent(url);

    this.showWaiting();
    this.ajax(proxyUrl, done);

    function done(result) {
      this.hideWaiting();
      var text = this.parseFeatureInfo(result, url);
      allText[j++] = text;
      if (j == layers.length) {
        callback.call(this, latlng, allText);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*Remark*: `.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper` style definition from question has to be removed to get popups of normal size.

Comment: I added your code before the wms source but no popup opens.

Comment: When I tested, I did it in IE11, and there it works OK. Now I checked also in Firefox and Chrome. If you check in browser debugger console, you'll see it reports CORS (cross origin request) policy violation when accessing GetFeatureInfo. I have no idea why since it's the same site as WMS layer.

Comment: clicking on the map is another way to understand which layers are overlapped and have a list of names in a popup?

Comment: See my modified answer.

Comment: My problem is that I have xampp apache and I have trouble seeing the proxy page like you did with asp

Comment: I have no experince with PHP, but I would say it's even simpler to write such page in PHP.

Comment: I installed php in my server

Comment: Added 'proxy' page example for PHP to the answer.

Comment: Well it works there, I put the php page in the root of my server and entered the proxy url in the JavaScript code.

Comment: Now my problem is another, under the "aree protette" and "zone umide" I have another layer of different origin that has as info format text / html

Comment: It would seem appropriate to accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: var ETRS89width= 18.99-5.93;
var startResolution = ETRS89width/1024;
var grid_resolution = new Array(22);
for (var i = 0; i < 22; ++i) {
 grid_resolution[i] = startResolution / Math.pow(2, i);
}


  var crs_6706 = new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG:6706',
 '+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs',
 {
  resolutions: grid_resolution,
  origin: [0, 0],
  bounds: L.bounds([5.93, 34.76], [18.99, 47.1])
 });





var options = {'transparent': true, 
crs: crs_6706,
 format: 'image/png',
    maxZoom: 21,
    transparent: true


};
var source = L.WMS.source("https://wms.cartografia.agenziaentrat